# Where is cli.ini letsencrypt config file?

Tags: lets-encrypt, rsa, keys

Where is the cli.ini file for default letsencrypt package?

From [Let's Encrypt docs](http://letsencrypt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html?highlight=rsa#configuration-file), it's possible to set default rsa key length in a `cli.ini` file, however, I cannot find this file.

I want to make sure that all my certs have the same key size as I initially started with the default setup, but I increased my last certificate's key length with `certbot renew --rsa-key-size 3072 --nginx`.

By changing this in cli.ini it would be global and I wouldn't have to worry about it.

I also noticed that there is a certbot cronjob in `/etc/cron.d`. Can I append `--nginx` to the command safely?

```
0 */12 * * * root test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(3600))' && certbot -q renew
```

would be

```
0 */12 * * * root test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(3600))' && certbot -q renew --nginx
```

Thanks awesomes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where is the cli.ini file for default letsencrypt package?

According to the documentation: “*By default, the following locations are searched: `/etc/letsencrypt/cli.ini`, `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/letsencrypt/cli.ini` (or `~/.config/letsencrypt/cli.ini` if `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is not set).*” The file does not necessarily exist by default, but you can certainly create it in one of the searched locations.

> I also noticed that there is a certbot cronjob in /etc/cron.d. Can I append --nginx to the command safely?

As this is a supported option, there should be no actual problem in adding it to the cron job, supposing you are actually running a nginx server. **However, as the documentation states that all available command-line options can be configured in the `cli.ini` file, rather put it there too**, for two main reasons: (a) **clarity** — better keep all configuration in a single place rather than specifying the key size in a config file and the used server in the cron job, and (b) **updates** — if the cron job has been created by a package manager (or any other form of installer), a future version might overwrite your changes, although most package managers warn users for modified configuration files that would get overwritten.

Comment: Thanks, I alos missed that line `The file does not necessarily exist by default` ;) - Thanks for the tips, I'll put everything in that file.

Comment: The "does not exist by default part" was *not* in the documentation ;)